# Next JS rewrite rule ternary condition

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am trying to use NextJS redirects.
My setups also makes use of `next-i18next` for i18n purposes.
I have the following configuration in `next.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: `/:locale/(rentals|locations)-:city`,
        destination: '/listing/:city',
        locale: false,
      },
    ];
  },
};
```

and this works pretty well ensuring that the following uris:

- `https://localhost:3000/fr/locations-paris`
- `https://localhost:3000/en/rentals-paris`

point to folder `/listing/[...slugs].tsx`.

The problem is that this does not prevent that hybrid language/slug uris could be served, such as:

- `https://localhost:3000/en/locations-paris /* en language, french slug */`
- `https://localhost:3000/fr/rentals-paris /* fr language, english slug */`

Is there a any way to setup a sort of condition on my rewrite rule, to make sure that en `:locale` is linked just to `rentals-` slug and fr `:locale` is linked just to `locations-` slug?

Comment: You probably need separate rewrite rules for each locale instead.